# How to let a for loop do my objectList printing

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Hi I want to put my prints in a for-loop. how to do it? So something like

```
if index = 0,1,2 print. 
if index = 2,3,4 print.
if index = 4,5,6 print.
```

Code:

```
     ArrayList<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>(res);

     System.out.println("\n\nThis starts to look like calculations:");
     System.out.print("\n" + objectList.get(0));
     System.out.print(" "+ objectList.get(1));
     System.out.print(" " + objectList.get(2) + " =");

     System.out.print("\n\n" + objectList.get(2));
     System.out.print(" " + objectList.get(3));
     System.out.print(" " + objectList.get(4)+ " =");

     System.out.print("\n\n" + objectList.get(4));
     System.out.print(" " + objectList.get(5));
     System.out.print(" " + objectList.get(6) + " =");
```

output: 
This starts to look like calculations:

```
1 + 3432.123 =

3432.123 * 4535 =

4535 - 24.4 =
```

Comment: Write what's inside res, please.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String buildOperation(int pos){
    String output;
    if(pos == 0) {
        output = "+";
    }else if(pos == 1){
        output = "*";
    }else {
        output = "-";
    }
    return output;
}

List<Object> objectList  = new ArrayList(res);

for(int i = 0; i < objectList.size()-1; i++){
    System.out.println(objectList.get(i) + buildOperation(i) + objectList.get(i+1) + "=");    
}
```

Additionaly I'll use a HashMap with the operations to avoid all if/else conditions

```
Map<Integer,String> operations = new HashMap{}
operations.put(0,"+");
operations.put(1,"*");
operations.put(2,"-");


System.out.println(objectList.get(i) + operations.get(i) + objectList.get(i+1) + "=");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Final solution now the String size does not matter anymore.

```
    ArrayList<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>(res);
    System.out.print("\n\nThis starts to look like calculations:");
    int maxi= objectList.size();
    maxi = maxi -2;
    System.out.println("\n\nmaxi = " + maxi);

    for (int i = 0; i < maxi; i+=2) {

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.print("\n\n" + objectList.get(i));
        System.out.print(" " + objectList.get(i + 1));
        System.out.print(" " + objectList.get(i + 2)+ " =");
```

Comment: This will only work when res.length() >= 7, and it will print more than the first 7.  This solution is very fragile and works only in your specific case.  Consider using a nested loop..

Comment: Why a break instead of another condition? (int i = 0; i < objectList.size() && i != 6; i+=2)

Comment: Problem is that the size will differ because different strings get insterted in my program so with another string the break wont work and your method neither.